# unserialize function is not returning returning string in same format

Tags: php, serialization

I am fetching serialized array from database and than trying to unserialize this. But here it is returning this string in a same format. I have this serialized array in this format.

```
s:33:"a:2:{i:0;s:2:"80";i:1;s:3:"112";}";
```

This is how I am trying to unserialize this.

```
$industries = unserialize($industries);
```

But here this function is not working. Any guidelines regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: _"In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned"_ Are you getting FALSE back?

Comment: Actually it is returning this array in a same format.

Comment: @AlexHowansky is there any way to fetch values from this kind of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is serialized twice,

```
s:33:"a:2:{i:0;s:2:"80";i:1;s:3:"112";}";
```

is a string (with 33 chars) encoded, so `unserialize()` this gives you another string which is

```
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"80";i:1;s:3:"112";}
```

you also need to `unserialize()` that...

```
$industries = 's:33:"a:2:{i:0;s:2:"80";i:1;s:3:"112";}";';
$industries = unserialize($industries);
print_r(unserialize($industries));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 80
    [1] => 112
)
```